# sf in r - one projection works, another throws an invalid geometry error

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, map-projections

I'm trying to draw some maps with `sf` and `ggplot2`, and I'm having some odd behaviour. I was running the map before using the EPSG projection number 3310, and that worked fine:

```
world <- st_read("world_map_path.shp")
syear <- st_read("data_path.shp")
proj <- 3310

ggplot(data = world) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  geom_sf(data=syear, aes(fill=owner), size=0.2) +
  coord_sf(crs=proj)
```

The above code returns no error, and renders a map perfectly well. However, running almost exactly the same code with a manually input orthographic projection results in an invalid geometry error. Code:

```
world <- st_read("world_map_path.shp")
syear <- st_read("data_path.shp")
proj <- "+proj=ortho +lon_0=35 +lat_0=90"

ggplot(data = world) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  geom_sf(data=syear, aes(fill=owner), size=0.2) +
  coord_sf(crs=proj)
```

Error:

```
Error in CPL_geos_is_empty(st_geometry(x)) :
  Evaluation error: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 2 - must be 0 or >= 4.
Calls: <Anonymous> ... st_as_grob.sfc_MULTIPOLYGON -> st_is_empty -> CPL_geos_is_empty
Execution halted
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there an error in my code, or in my input data? What might said error be?

Comment: Could you try to filter out (potential) empty geometries via  ``syear <- st_read("data_path.shp") %>% filter(!st_is_empty(geometry))``.

Comment: @mgrund That just throws an error -
    Error in data.matrix(data) : 
      'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
    Calls: %>% ... filter -> as.ts -> as.ts.default -> ts -> data.matrix

Comment: What do you receive when applying ``st_is_valid()`` to your two dfs containing the geometries? Seems like some of your data contains invalid polygons (rings with less than 4 points).

Comment: @mgrund That's the odd part - it returns a pile of valid polygons for the first and at least one invalid polygon for the second, but removing the second data source entirely and just plotting the first still results in the error. In short, according to `st_is_valid()` there's no invalid polygons in the first data set, but when I run the program on only the first data set it still returns an invalid polygon error. That error goes away with a different map projection.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same exact issue when doing an orthogonal projection with sf. I've tried everything from st_make_valid() and also tried a solution to make sure geometries don't disappear when rotating along the globe using ortho. When I use a data frame and coord_map() instead of sf, it works fine.